# problem with deleting a directory and subdirectory

Tags: directory

```
root@Umar:/home/umar# rmdir /usr/local/Reliance_Netconnect
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/usr/local/Reliance_Netconnect’: Directory not empty
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a non-empty directory in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a directory that is not empty, you need to use `rm -rf`.

This is basic linux, and so is using sudo instead of a root account; you're setting yourself up for disaster. Be careful.

Comment: you *don't* need to use `-f` and might be a bad suggestion for someone who appears to not know what they're doing. also, `sudo` is not necessarily "basic Linux." there's still a camp that believes it makes more sense to use the `root` account. it *is* basic Debian/Ubuntu/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must have an empty directory for `rmdir` to work.

The typical way to recursively delete a directory and all of it's contents is with the `rm -r` command where the `-r` is short for recursive.