# Why do I get "Directory not empty" when I try to remove an empty directory?

Tags: command-line, files, delete

I have this empty directory, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Cannot remove test: Directory not empty
```

I know this question has been asked plenty of times but none of them helped.

I tried `ls -la` to make sure there were no hidden files, and there does not seem to be: 
[image]

I tried `sudo rmdir test` as well as `sudo rm -rf test`, and I just do not know what is wrong.

I read it might be a problem with the file system, but I have no idea how I would go about fixing that.

Comment: Try `sudo fsck /`

Comment: Is it a normal directory or a mount point. If this is a mount point, it should be unmounted before deleting. If it is a normal directory, sometime there might be some open handles cause this problem. Reboot your machine once and try to delete it.

Comment: @rbrick Does `test` is your login user's name? what is the output of `echo $USER`? and what `echo $HOME`?

Comment: I am confused, why does the user not have execute permissions on the directory, but group does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a non-empty directory in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal)

Comment: not a dup - user already use "-rf" but did not work.

Comment: Hidden files are there.

Comment: Emptying the trash bin before deleting again worked for me.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had the same problem on a external hard disk, I tried so many ways using command line, but I failed every time. 
That's what worked for me:

1. Right click on folder
2. Move to trash
3. Empty trash

Yes, it's silly but it worked for me (I don't really know how and why, but the damned folder no longer exist)

Comment: I got the same issue and your answer works. Not quite sure what the silly thing happened, and why "-rf" failed to remove an non-empty folder.

Comment: What just happened here? Why did it work?

Comment: What happened? Honestly, i don't know. Maybe, the folder's file was corrupted for some reason: a flag like "is-empty" or the file counter like "how-many-file-inside" has been setted to an erroneous value. Sometimes, errors like this could be caused by damages on the hard disk.
Why did it work? I don't know how commands are implemented (think about C), but I guess they check those flags and counters before acting (i mean, if file counter >0 then "error: directory not empty" and abort), while emptying the trash directly remove the folder and all its file and subfolder without any kind of check.

Comment: Maybe, deleting a folder through command line requires some conditions, like the emptiness of the folder, (because removing the folder's node from file system removes only that single linknode and requires the folder to be empty so no other file-node would be "forgot" through the file system due to losing the intermediate link to them, represented by the folder) ..
and deleting a folder through right click -> delete or emptying the trash removes the folder AND all file and subfolders recursively, not caring of flags, counters and stuffs like that (so, no checks are performed)

Comment: I repeat, i don't know the exact reason, i'm just guessing, because i don't know how the file system, commands and the whole OS are implemented and programmed.

Comment: In my case, the subdirectory in question happened to be in a folder that was shared from my Mac to a linux VM, and I was trying to delete the folder from the linux VM side.  It seems that the Mac side was holding onto some folders.  Doing the `rm -rf` from the Mac side worked.

Comment: This moves the directory to .Trash where it sits prohibiting operations on the attributes of the entire drive.

Comment: This just moves the corrupted folders from `.Trash-1000/files` to `.Trash-1000/expunged` where they remain undeletable.

Comment: Strange that `sudo rm -rf` did not work, but this did. @Sebastian, the corrupted folder did not reside in .Trash/expunged.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue not able to remove directory as it is not empty.

This sequence of operations worked for me.

1. From command line first

   ```
   sudo rmdir  --ignore-fail-on-non-empty folder-name-to-be-deleted
   ```

The above command helps ubuntu ignore directory is not empty.

2. Then just go to the folder and Shift + Del. That is all.

Comment: Shift+Delete was enough for me

Comment: thanks, `rmdir` worked!

Answer (score 11):

I have win 10 + ubuntu dual system installed. And both systems share the windows parititions.

Recently, i also ran into unable to delete empty folders in those partitions under ubuntu. I can't find out solution to solve it under linux.

However, after i switch to windows, and run

```
chkdsk
```

via `cmd` for the target disk. Some errors checked out.
and then i run

```
chkdsk /F
```

to fix disk error.

After it finish, i am able to delete those folders now.

Comment: This method works for me. I think it is also important to note that the shared partition(s) is NTFS formatted and that it is probably corrupted.

Comment: Luckily still have access access to a native Windows machine. For all others, [`ntfsfix` (existing in most distros) might be of help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398186/156470). (feedback if that works appreciated!)

Answer (score 6):

You could delete it by typing `sudo rm -rf {dir_name}`. The directory might have been set to read-only permission. I hope the given command can delete the folder.

Comment: I get `Directory not empty` anyway. It seems strange, so I recorded my screen to prove.

Comment: That command in the answer works even if directory has contents and also with subdirectories.

Comment: don't believe me just watch :D https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UEYVa4UT6df7xucrq-lO82xjk3afHHzA

Comment: this strange behaviour was caused by errors in NTFS partition. solved with `chkdsk /F`.

Answer (score 6):

If the directory is part of a filesystem mounted with CIFS (aka samba), and it contains a file that is a broken symbolic link, then `ls` fails to mention that file.  (I observe this **bug** on a CIFS client running 14.04.2 LTS, and a server running 12.04.5 LTS.)

So *the directory is not empty*, but (over CIFS) you have no way to see that.  The file can only be seen, and thus can only be deleted, by a command running on the fileserver hosting that filesystem.

Comment: Gah, this was it! Is it me, or is CIFS just buggy and slow as f****?

Comment: Seven years later and *still* no fix means it's not just you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using btrfs, it is possibly an empty directory with a non-zero i_size. You can check whether this is the case with:

```
stat -c %s test
```

The i_size of an empty folder in btrfs should be zero. In my case, I got 6160 with `~/.config/chromium/Default`.

The suggested solution is to unmount the filesystem, run `btrfs check` to confirm the issue and check for other problematic directories, and finally run `btrfs check --repair` to fix. This operation is risky, though, so it's a good idea to backup files first.

Source: [Btrfs Problem FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_cannot_delete_an_empty_directory)

Answer (score 3):

### GUI solution

1. Move or cut & paste the folder to trash folder
2. empty the trash

it is done.

### Command-line solution

```
sudo mv folder_error/ .local/share/Trash
```

you can clear with trash-cli: trash-empty
or

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

Comment: I think the command line solution here is actually a general solution.  Move the empty folder to another location, and remove it once it's moved.  E.g., something like this `mkdir a ; mv test a/ ; rm -rf a/test ; rm -rf a`.  An approach like that worked for me (although I have no idea why it would), and I didn't need root access.

Comment: Your comment should be the accepted answer lol

Answer (score 2):

try this command:

```
sudo lsof | grep deleted
```

Check in the list if your directory is still in use. :D

If so, stop the service and you will be able delete the directory.

Comment: Obviously the directory won't show up in the list of open, deleted file descriptors if it can't be deleted. ;-]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 and I fixed it by:

1. emptying the trash folder
2. rebooting

Opening and closing the file manager did no good—only rebooting worked.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears when those folders or files are not copied completely. It's Input/Output Error. I tried to delete with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or through commands, but these did not work. I tried right click and "Move to Trash" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if directory is not active for any running application before deleting. I was unable to delete a directory with same message, I found out the reason was that the directory was open in an node.js application. After closing/exiting the application I was able to delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a separate command that ran concurrently and added  files while the delete was ongoing; likely rm finished deleting everything it had planned to delete, then tried to delete the folder at the end, saw it had contents, and then threw an error saying 'yo, something is not right'.

(It had to do with running code in serial vs. accidentally in parallel for me.)

You may consider this if you're dealing with this problem.

Comment: Same here - I had a concurrent process running an un-tar command into that directory

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and found that the solution was quite simple for me.

I had a Node server running that periodically accessed the files in the folder I was trying to remove. This caused several small meta files to constantly exist inside the folder. The purpose of these files is beyond me.

Even `rm -rf folder/*` would not remove these files permanently, despite showing the message `removed folder/file.xyz`.

I suspected the server, shut it down and removed the files and the folder without fail.

Comment: This answer seems *really* edge-casey … 

Comment: Very much an edge case. Nonetheless resulted in exactly this error, and my initial debugging endeavour lead me here. Perhaps it will help the next person who makes the same oversight I did ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the directory or a file in it has an immutable bit set?

```
root@lina:~# mkdir test
root@lina:~# chattr +i test
root@lina:~# rmdir test
rmdir: konnte 'test' nicht entfernen: Die Operation ist nicht erlaubt
root@lina:~# lsattr -d test
----i---------e---- test
root@lina:~# chattr -i test
root@lina:~# rmdir test
```

then you should remove the immutable bit with ''chattr -i'' first.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `rm` command recursive flag i.e.

`rm -r folder/`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PkLl.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the [`rm` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/rm-invocation.html)

```
       -d, --dir
              remove empty directories
```

So, to extend your example, try removing the directory with `rm -drf test/`

Answer (score -2):

I solved a similar problem:

The actual error I got is:

```
find: cannot delete ‘/home/lucid/x/SecurityCameras/B-Yard’: Directory not empty
```

The command I used was:

```
find /home/lucid/x/SecurityCameras/B-Yard -mtime +15 -delete
```

The directory inside `/home/lucid/x/SecurityCameras/B-Yard` is `2021`, which is put there by the camera.
Deleting OR renaming the directory to something else and then back to `2021` FIXED the problem. Renaming and back again for `B-Yard` didn't do anything.
So just renaming the offending directory to something else, and then back to the original name fixes the problem. No need to delete anything.