# Cannot remove non-empty dir with rm -rf

Tags: command-line, bash, delete

I try to remove directories that contain files in the command line by using rm -rf dir1. However,I receive error message telling

```
rm: cannot remove 'dir1': Directory not empty
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Possible answers:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/566474/why-do-i-get-directory-not-empty-when-i-try-to-remove-an-empty-directory?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

found the solution. A file called *fuse_hidden* produced the issues. I wasn't able to delete that file, even in not by rightclicking and deleting.

I used lsof dir/*fuse_hidden* to show processes using this file and closed them. After that I rm -rf was possible.