# Command to delete a directory with files in it

Tags: command-line, scripts, delete

I am trying to write a shell script that deletes a persistent but unnecessary folder in my home directory upon execution. So, I ask you fellow Ubuntu users, what is the terminal command to delete a file/folder?

Comment: No, I want the terminal command to delete a file in general. But I'll check it out.

Comment: in case of a file use `rm`, in case of a directory `rm -r` (if empty `rmdir` will work)

Comment: This link might be what you're after? 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal

Comment: That gave me my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The Command  `rm`

if you want to remove a directory you need to use `rm` with option -R

`rm -R`

check the option for `rm`

by typing `rm --help`